# How could I get fluentd to retain a value from one event then add it to all the following events?

Tags: fluentd

Is there a way to have fluentd retain a value from one event, then append that value to all events from another soruce, until it recieves another similiar event with a new value for that field?

For example I am now capturing:

```
2024-01-12 07:19:49.292623900 +0100 Log.A: {"SerialNumber":"1001"}
2024-01-12 07:19:50.000000000 +0100 Log.B: {"message":"abcdefg123"}
2024-01-12 07:19:51.000000000 +0100 Log.B: {"message":"hijkmnl456"}
2024-01-12 08:30:53.072297300 +0100 Log.A: {"SerialNumber":"1002"}
2024-01-12 08:31:00.000000000 +0100 Log.B: {"message":"opqrst789"}
2024-01-12 08:32:00.000000000 +0100 Log.B: {"message":"uvwxyz012"}
```

And I would like to get:

```
2024-01-12 07:19:49.292623900 +0100 Log.A: {"SerialNumber":"1001"}
2024-01-12 07:19:50.000000000 +0100 Log.B: {"message":"abcdefg123","SerialNumber":"1001"}
2024-01-12 07:19:51.000000000 +0100 Log.B: {"message":"hijkmnl456","SerialNumber":"1001"}
2024-01-12 08:31:20.072297300 +0100 Log.A: {"SerialNumber":"1002"}
2024-01-12 08:31:34.000000000 +0100 Log.B: {"message":"opqrst789","SerialNumber":"1002"}
2024-01-12 08:31:56.000000000 +0100 Log.B: {"message":"uvwxyz012","SerialNumber":"1002"}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to my mind is to use Concat filter and regexp filters or record_transform with some ruby code to tier it down, but still, not a great solution.
How ever, keep in mind that fluentd is just a log agregator ands its not meant to do complex transformation or logics.

However, here are the doc of what I suggested:

- concat: https://github.com/fluent-plugins-nursery/fluent-plugin-concat
- record transform: https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/record_transformer